# Call a C# function in ASP.NET when clicking on a HTML link

Tags: c#, html, asp.net

I have some inputs and some TextAreas in my `myEditPage.aspx` page and I wish to upload them to a database but to do so I need to link a `<a href="..">` to a function in my `myEditPage.aspx.cs`.

How can I do so?

Answer (score 40, accepted):

Instead of

```
<a href=.....>
```

use

```
<asp:LinkButton id="myid" runat="server" OnClick="MyFunction_Click" />
```

[LinkButton](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.linkbutton.aspx) is an ASP.Net server side control

Of course, you can attach a function to an `<a>` tag as well. Just make it a server control by adding runat=server to it.

```
<a href="#" runat="server" onServerClick="MyFuncion_Click" />
```

Then in your function retrieve the values of your textareas and inputs.

In general, use asp.net controls instead of regular html controls. It makes it easier to program asp.net.

For textarea/input use `<asp:TextBox>`. If you google a bit you will find many tutorials to get you started with asp.net programming. For example: http://www.asp.net/

Comment: @abatishchev You´re a case nut ;) I usually keep all my tags lowercase :)

Comment: I just made it a bit more compilable =) Sorry if disquieted

Comment: No problem, and fixing the spelling was smart :)

Comment: for the html element (`<a href="#"... ` you'll need to have `OnServerClick` intead of `onClick` to trigger your click event in code behind. So it would look like this: `<a href="#" runat="server" OnServerClick="MyFuncion_Click" />`

Comment: @MikaelSvenson great insights. I am currently testing out html textbox because it has *proper* `readonly` property. e.g. `<input type="text" id="dateFrom" readonly="readonly" />` But if I use asp.net textbox, the readonly doesn't help to achieve the same. `<asp:TextBox ID ="dateFromTBox" runat="server" ReadOnly="true">` Yes in terms of accessing data to client side, asp.net controls are much user friendly with its event handling capabilities. Can you enlighten me if asp.net TextBox can be properly `readonly`? Then I could use `onTextChange` event to do the validation and data biding.

Comment: @bonCodigo, you can do textBox.Attributes["readonly"] = "readonly" in your codebehind. Not sure if there's a different way.