# how to call function from html file in asp.net

Tags: asp.net

i'm new to asp.net

i want to call function from my html file
I have a html file containing a list of menu

```
<a href="">Menu 1</a>
```

and i have a file name home.aspx, i want to call a function in home.aspx.cs with that hyperlink

I have tried this but still can not
[Call a C# function in ASP.NET when clicking on a HTML link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4537490/call-a-c-sharp-function-in-asp-net-when-clicking-on-a-html-link-a)

sorry for my English, English is not my native language
please help me

is my first code name home.aspx

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="home.aspx.cs" Inherits="user_home" %>
<% Response.WriteFile("tools/menu.htm"); %>
```

and this is home.aspx.cs

```
public partial class user_home : System.Web.UI.Page
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e){
}
```

and this is my `menu.htm`

```
<div id="menu">
<ul>
<li><a href="#">Menu1</a></li>
</ul>
</div>
```

sorry for trouble

Answer (score 0):

```
<a href="#" runat="server" id="link">Menu 1</a>
```

You should use runat="server" attribute.

Comment: i try this
`<a href="#" runat="server" id="Menu1" onclick="Menu1_Click">Menu 1</a>`
but still not running

Comment: Do you have some special code in Page_Load, Page_Init? Try to check web page in different browsers.

Comment: do we should declare a something first in the page_load?
 because i do not have any code in my page_load?
 sorry for trouble, i newbie in asp

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you are not looking for a `LinkButton`???

This control renders in the client as:

```
<a href="javascript to post... automatically generated">Click me...</a>
```

### ASPX

```
<asp:LinkButton Text="Click me..." runat="server" ID="myLink" Click="myLink_Click" />
```

### Code behind

```
protected void myLink_click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // write here your cool stuff as a response of the click event
}
```

If you insist to use an HtmlControl, then:

### In ASPX

```
<a href="#" runat="server" id="myLink2" onserverclick="myLink2_Click">Menu 1</a>
```

### IN code behind

```
protected void myLink2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // write here your cool stuff as a response of the click event
}
```

Comment: i can't add `linkbutton`
i try `<li><asp:LinkButton Text="Menu1" runat="server" ID="Logout" OnClick="Menu1_Click" /></li>` but it didn't show anything
i try this in html

Comment: it works, please post the code you have tried so I can help you

Comment: I just updated the answer to use an HtmlControl (a simple `<a>` control