# Finding the ID of a link

Tags: c#, html, asp.net

I have added links dynamically to an asp page. On clicking, I call a function. I want to find out the id of the link that is calling the function. I have added google.com and yahoo.com to explain my needs. I want the function to pull data from db in the original scenario which I have done.

```
 <a href="#"  onServerClick="abc_Click" id="4"/>click</a>
 <a href="#" onServerClick="abc_Click" id="5"/>click here</a>
```

C# code:

```
 protected void abc_Click()
 {
    if(id is 4) // don't know how to know the id of the link that calls the function. 
      Response.Redirect("http://www.google.com");
    else
      Response.Redirect("http://www.yahoo.com");
 }
```

I referred [Call a C# function in ASP.NET when clicking on a HTML link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4537490/call-a-c-sharp-function-in-asp-net-when-clicking-on-a-html-link-a) .

Now I have two problems.

1. The function is not getting called when link is clicked.
2. I do not know to how to find the id of the link that calls the function.

Comment: you have to add `runat="server"`.

Comment: or use a `LinkButton`.

Comment: Sorry that I didn't mention that. I added runat="server" and it is still not working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're missing the runat-server attribute. If you include this, you need to have the link in a form. But you can't pass the ID of the link to the server (unless you first modify a hidden field with JS and then post the hidden field). However, that is a very complex solution to a rather simple problem.

The easiest way is to just add a querystring and then do the db call in the Page_Load.

Example:

```
<a href="/mypage.aspx?id=4" />click</a>
<a href="/mypage.aspx?id=5" />click here</a>
```

And then in the code-behind:

```
public void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if(Request.QueryString["id"] == "4")
    {
        Response.Redirect("http://www.google.com");
    }
    else
    {
        Response.Redirect("http://www.yahoo.com");
    }
}
```

Comment: It works fine if I hard code it in my aspx file. I want to add <a href="/mypage.aspx?id=5" />click here</a> from my aspx.cs file. I tried storing it a string and adding it to HTML through element.InnerHtml, but it is treated as a string and hence it is not working. Help please

Answer (score 2):

You missed an important attribute for referencing these links server-side:

```
runat="server"
```

It should be something like this:

```
<a href="#" runat="server" onServerClick="abc_Click" id="4"/>click</a>
<a href="#" runat="server" onServerClick="abc_Click" id="5"/>click here</a>
```

How are you adding these dynamically, by the way?  Hopefully server-side.  Because if they're being added via JavaScript on the client then it's too late for the server to bind events to them.

It's also recommended that you don't make these links, since they're not actually linking to anything.  (The `href="#"` just tells it to go to the top of the page.)  Since these are supposedly posting to the server to enact some server-side action, they be better off as buttons.  (Which would make what you're trying to do a lot easier, by the way.)  Buttons can be styled to look like links if necessary for the UX.

Your server-side handler also needs additional arguments:

```
protected void abc_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
```

In this case, `sender` will be the element that's been clicked.  You can cast it to that element's type and get all the information you need from it, including its `.Id` property.

Comment: @Srinivas: Can you be more specific?  In what way is it not working?  What does the client-side HTML look like?  Hint: If `runat="server"` is visible in the client-side emitted HTML then you're somehow adding these links incorrectly.  How are you dynamically adding them?

Comment: Function is not getting called. The page source view in my browser shows runat="server". When I click on the link, the function is not getting called.

Comment: @Srinivas: You're adding them incorrectly, then.  They're being added as plain text to the output instead of actual server-side controls.  So the function isn't getting called because you're not binding it to any actual server-side controls.  The easiest approach at this point would probably be similar to Kenneth's answer.  Just have the links be normal HTML links which call the current page and pass some query string value.  Then just check for that value in `Page_Load`.

Comment: I feel the same. Kenneth answer should work. I will still need to know how to post a asp link from a c# code that calls the function onServerClick. Only with your answer, I recognized that it is being added as plain text to the output instead of actual server-side controls

Comment: @Srinivas: The difference is going to be entirely in how you are dynamically adding this output.  If you want to dynamically add controls, you should probably do it in something like `Page_Init` (or even sooner?) and add them as actual control elements (to the `Controls` collection, maybe inside a `PlaceHolder` or something) in code instead of as strings.

Answer (score 1):

add runat="server" to your html markup to have the element available on your server.
Otherwise it is just an html element and those obviously cannot be accessed on the server...

```
<a href="#" runat="server" onServerClick="abc_Click" id="4" />
```

You would also have to implement the event handler correctly because your implementation is missing the parameters

Comment: Sorry that I didn't mention. I added runat="server" and it is still not working.